# NGINX How to add header only if upstream cache is HIT?

Tags: nginx

I want to add header. Only If upstream cache is HIT

I use this in location block but not success:

```
    if ($upstream_cache_status = "HIT") {
        expires 1m;
        add_header "X-Test-Header" "testvalue";
    }
```

Using add_trailer also not succees. What is the solution?